# Is there an O(1) algorithm for generating the result of a series of random events?

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

Let's say I've got a routine that, when invoked, will use a RNG and return `True` 30% of the time, or `False` otherwise.  That's fairly simple.  But what if I wanted to simulate how many `True` results I'd get if I called that routine 10 billion times?

Calling it 10 billion times in a loop would take too long.  Multiplying 10 billion by 30% would yield the statistically expected result of 3 billion, but there would be no actual randomness involved.  (And the odds that the result would be *exactly* 3 billion aren't all that great.)

Is there an algorithm for simulating the aggregate result of such a series of random events, such that if it were called multiple times, the results it gave would show the same distribution curve as actually running the random series it's simulating multiple times, that runs in O(1) time (ie. does not take longer to run as the length of the series to be simulated increases)?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you either know the characteristics of the generating function or you don't?

Comment: As written, this might be off-topic.  You're going to want to read up on the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say - **it can be done in O(1)!**

[Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) which describes your situation can (in some circumstances) be approximated by normal distribution. It can be done when both `n*p` and `n*(1-p)` are greater then 5, so for `p=0.3` it can be done for all `n > 17`. When `n` is getting really big (like millions) that approximation is getting better and better.

A random number with normal distribution can be easily calculated using [Box–Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). All you need to do that are two random numbers between 0 and 1. Box-Muller transform gives two random numbers from `N(0,1)` distribution, called standard normal. `N(μ, σ2)` can be achieved using `X = μ + σZ` formula, where `Z` is standard normal.

Comment: For an exact solution, have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988824/is-there-an-o1-algorithm-for-generating-the-result-of-a-series-of-random-event/14989735#14989735)

Answer (score 1):

After a deeper thought I can present this Python solution, which works in O(log(n)) and does not use any approximation. However, for large n the solution of @MarcinJuraszek is more suitable.

- First I generate a Python list with values of [Cumulative Binomial Distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).
- Later I use [Inverse Transform Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

The cost of the first step is O(n) -- but you have to do it only once. The cost of the second step is just O(log(n)) -- which is essentially a cost of a binary search. As the code has many dependencies, you can take a look at this screenshot:

[image: screenshot with plots showing the distributions]

```
import numpy.random as random
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import scipy.stats as stats
import bisect

# This is the number of trials.
size = 6;

# this generates in memory an object, which contains
# a full information on desired binomial
# distribution. The object has to be generated only once.
# THIS WORKS IN O(n).
binomialInstance = stats.binom(size, 0.3)

# this pulls a probabilty mass function in form of python list
binomialTable = [binomialInstance.pmf(i) for i in range(size + 1)]

# this pulls a python list from binomialInstance, first
# processing it to produce a cumulative distribution function.
binomialCumulative = [binomialInstance.cdf(i) for i in range(size + 1)]

# this produces a plot of dots: first argument is x-axis (just
# subsequent integers), second argument is our table.
pyplot.plot([i for i in range(len(binomialTable))], binomialTable, 'ro')
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.plot([i for i in range(len(binomialCumulative))], binomialCumulative, 'ro')

# now, we can cheaply draw a sample from our distribution.
# we can use bisect to draw a random answer.
# THIS WORKS IN log(n).
cutOff = random.random(1)
print "this is our cut-off value: " + str(cutOff)
print "this is a number of successful trials: " + str(bisect.bisect(binomialCumulative, cutOff))
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As other reviewers mentioned you can use binomial distribution. But, since you are dealing with a very large number of samples you should consider using normal distribution approximation.